# Autostop recording video after x seconds

Tags: java, android, android-mediarecorder

i'm an absolute beginner with android studio and java. this is my first post. I was using Youtube tutorials to  try and make a simple video app that records in the background. 
The app works fine, it has a start and stop button for triggering. I can trigger start recording and record for 5 seconds, But the app wont save the file until i trigger the stop button. 
How do i get the stop functionality to trigger after 5seconds is reached? Here's some code that may help understand my problem. I want to be able to bake the stop and release functionality after 5sec.

mServiceCamera.unlock();

```
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mServiceCamera);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/video.mp4");
        mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(5000);
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());



        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        mMediaRecorder.start();


        mRecordingStatus = true;

        return true;
```

Comment: use timer or threads to resolve your problem.

Comment: you can use like mediaPlayer starts as the timer starts and stops when the mediaPlayer stops.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can u please elaborate on this if possible? I'm a beginner.. Also, i'm not playing the media at all.. There is no preview. It just records video in the background